# Block all internet except 2 URLs from 8 am to 8 pm and unblock all between 8pm and 8am on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dns, web-filtering

I have a friend that has a hard time concentrating when working at home on his laptop running windows7.
He asked me to find a way to put the following filter on his laptop:
 - from 8am to 8pm (when he needs to study) to block all internet traffic except a few sites that he needs for his work (university etc)
 - from 8pm to 8am (time for a break) he wants to have normal access to the internet, be able to check his mail and so on.

I first underestimated the task as I thought I could use a very good free program that I used to use for such goals on Vista and XP. But this program doesn't work on windows 7.

On top of this, I cannot set up any hosts file as first it cannot block everything (the list would be too long...) and I cannot setup time.

I wasn't too keen about using the windows 7 builtin filtering as I thought it could be good and useful for him to still have full access to his laptop (and so not to have "not to know" his own admn password and being forced to use a standard user). Maybe I am wrong though.

So I thought about using opendns, customize the free settings to block everything and then find a way to switch the dns settings of windows 7 at 8 pm and 8 am, as to use the opendns settings or not.
But I cannot find any switcher that does this automatically at precise times (dnsflushing could also be useful).

Answer (score 2):

simply set up 2 scheduled tasks, one for 8:00am and make it execute this command to use the Opendns server

```
netsh dnsclient set dnsservers name="connection_name_here" static 208.67.222.222 primary
```

and another for 8:00pm, and use this to reset it

```
netsh dnsclient set dnsservers name="connection_name_here" source=dhcp
```

and check [Run with highest privileges] when creating the task with the wizard.